# (Easy) Identifying a function from a table

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I found this problem in an Algebra book, and it should be easy, but I can't solve it for some reason.

The table of ordered pairs (x,y) gives an exponential function. Write an equation for that function.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
  \text{x} & \text{y} \\ \hline
 -1 & 2 \\ \hline
 0 & 6 \\ \hline
1 & 18 \\ \hline
 2 & 54 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The only thing that I can get from it is that it is ______+6

Comment: $2\times 3^{x+1}$ works.  If you prefer, $6\times 3^x$.

Comment: Ah, I never thought of that, guess I was too focused on the $+6$ part

Comment: If you divide the right-hand column by $2$ you get something pretty recognizable.